# Find count in aggregate lookup

Tags: mongodb-query

I am looking to find out the total documents count from aggregate join. if anybody have an idea please let me know. And this my code

```
        db.collection("camp", function (err, camp) {
        camp.aggregate([{$match: {status: {$ne: "Rejected"}}}, 
             {'$lookup': {

                    from: "organization",
                    localField: "organization",
                    foreignField: "organizationId",
                    as: "orgnData"
                }
            }, {'$lookup': {
                    from: "organizer",
                    localField: "organizer",
                    foreignField: "organizerId",
                    as: "ornrData"
                }},
            {$unwind: "$orgnData"},
            {$unwind: "$ornrData"},
            {$match: {'ornrData.city': 'Nagpur'}},

            {$skip: 0}, {$limit: 10}, 
            {$sort: {id: -1}}

        ], function (err, info) {
            res.json(info);
        });
    });
```

In the above code i am looking to get total rows count of result before limit to use pagination bar. if anybody have an idea please let me know?

Comment: You can use **$group** for counting number of similar collection which cities Nagpur or can choose your criteria. If you need more detail please share your dummy collection data.